# python: how to add a new key and a value in yaml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have the following YAML file. I need to update the YAML file with a new key-value pair using python.

I am doing the following but, it gives me error:

```
pod = mylib.load_yaml("net/pod.yaml")
pod['spec']['nodeSelector']['key']='val'
```

it gives error saying `KeyError:'nodeSelector'`

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ceridwen/networking:v1
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: networking
    readinessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 5000
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 1
    restartPolicy: Always
```

I need to update it with a new key value

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ceridwen/networking:v1
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: networking
    readinessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 5000
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 1
    restartPolicy: Always
  nodeSelector:
    key: value
```

Comment: `pod["spec"] = {"nodeSelector": {"key": "val"}}` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you load that YAML file, your `pod` is a dict with a single key `spec`. You can check the value for that key (`print(pod['spec']`) and you'll see that that is dict, with a single key `containers`. Since you want add an extra key `nodeSelector` to that dict you should add to `pod['spec']`:

```
pod['spec']['nodeSelector'] = dict(key='value')
```

Please note that the `key:value` you had in your output (without a space after the `:` and without quotes around `key` and `value`), is not a mapping but a single scalar string.

---

The "solution" given by @zwer in his comment:

`pod["spec"] = {"nodeSelector": {"key": "val"}}`
is incorrect, as it will dump as:

```
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    key: val
```

i.e. replacing the value for `spec` and thereby deleting the existing dict/mapping with the key `containers`.

Comment: Awesome anthon, I actually followed @zwer solution and debugged it for 4 hours on what could be wrong then realized after printing everything.