# Python3 - YAML not correctly appending values in list

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

Snippet of the .yml file:

```
- hosts: arbiters
  roles:
    - role: roles/arbiters
      vars:
        machines:
          arb-1:
            - repset: r-11
              mongoversion: 4.2
              port: 27017
            - repset: r-17
              mongoversion: 4.2
              port: 27018
```

I want to append sub-keys with values using Python:

```
            - repset: my_own_value
              mongoversion: 40000
              port: 1
```

The following code works partially

```
data[0]['roles'][0]['vars']['machines']['arb-2'] = dict(mongoversion='40000', port='1', repset='my_own_value')
```

gives

```
'arb-2': {'mongoversion': 40000,
          'port': '1',
          'repset': 'my_own_value'}
```

This is incorrect, as I want to append, instead of replace.
When I use the `+=` operator, instead of `=`, it gives:

```
'arb-2': [{'mongoversion': 4.2,
           'port': 27017,
           'repset': 'r-10'},
          {'mongoversion': 4.2,
           'port': 27018,
           'repset': 'r-16'},
           'mongoversion',
           'port',
           'repset']
```

Now, the values are missing. I've followed the [answer as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030819/python-how-to-add-a-new-key-and-a-value-in-yaml-file), and tried to play around with several settings, but I don't seem to succeed.

Comment: Are you sure the file extension has to be `.yml`? For over 12 years the [officially recommended extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html) for YAML files has been `.yaml`

Comment: Irrelevant discussion for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, your element `['arb-1']` isn't of type `dict`, it is of type `list`.
So actually you should do the following:

```
data[0]['roles'][0]['vars']['machines']['arb-2'].append({'mongoversion'="v40000",'port'=1,'repset'="my_own_value"})
```

or in short

```
data["some"]["path"].append({'your':"object",'values':"here"})
```

---

**-- edit --**

Here is a complete test program. Dependency can be installed with `pip install pyyaml`.

```
import yaml

yaml_doc = """
  a: 1
  b:
    c:
      - a: b
        e: f
      - c: d
    d: 4
"""

doc = yaml.load(yaml_doc, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

print(type(doc["b"]["c"]))
print doc

doc["b"]["c"].append({"x":2,"w":"i","u":'t'})
print doc
```

Comment: Thanks, seems that `.update` is used to update a list.